# How to call a method of a Generic T?

Tags: c#, class, generics

```
namespace TestingConsole
{
    class Test<TA, TB>
    {
        TA _value1;
        TB _value2;

        public Test(TA t, TB t1)
        {
            _value1 = t;
            _value2 = t1;
        }

        void Write()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ATest: " + ((ATest)_value1).GetValue());
            // Here I get "type TA cannot be converted to ATest"
        }
    }

    class ATest
    {
        private int x;

        public void SetValue(int y)
        {
            x = y;
        }

        public int GetValue()
        {
            return x;
        }
    }

    class BTest
    {
        private string x;

        public void SetValue(string y)
        {
            x = y;
        }

        public string GetValue()
        {
            return x;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ATest at = new ATest();
            BTest bt = new BTest();
            Test<ATest, BTest> test = new Test<ATest, BTest>(at, bt);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

If I create a generic class (where TA and TB can be anything), how do I access the specific functions in each?

ATest.GetValue() returns an int.

BTest.GetValue() returns a string.

It seems like somehow I need to cast TA to an ATest (but obviously this isn't working).

Let me try to further explain. Maybe generics isn't my answer.

I have a collection of 6 data acquisition classes and 3 device classes. In the device classes, the code is identical except for the DAQ classes. Each device class gets two of the DAQ classes. I would like to put all of this into a single class but at run time I don't know which DAQ class will be called.

I was thinking that with generics I could create a single class and pass the two DAQ classes in as parameters.  Each device class has to have two specific DAQ classes. They aren't interchangeable.

Comment: Cleary `Test` isn't actually generic, if it needs to be given a `TestA`, and not an object of *any* type.

Comment: If you know it's an `ATest`, why have a generic parameter? The point of generics is when you don't need/want to know which class it is.

Comment: I really hope those `GetValue` and `SetValue` methods are pseudo-code and not actual code and that you in fact use properties for that

Comment: I cobbled this together quickly.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Why do you hope that about the GetValue and SetValue, seems like valid accessor mutator methods to me.

Comment: @RyanWilson because if you are trying to get or set a value you use a property.  Thats why they exist

Comment: @maccettura There is nothing wrong with using accessor/mutator functions, it's just an older style.

Comment: What do you think the compiler does when you declare a public property?? It achieves the same thing as having a private variable with an accessor GET method and a mutator SET method.

Comment: @RyanWilson Its 2018, the language has come a long way.  Do you still write your own state machines for async/await?  Do you still build implementations of a list instead of using `System.Collections.Generic.List`?  Properties exist to you can get and set the value of something.  In general, you use methods to represent actions and properties to represent data.  This is all basic C#/.NET design guidelines.

Comment: @maccettura I come from a C++ background. I do use properties in C# but I just typed this quickly.

Comment: @DanielS You can use whichever style you like, it's just a matter of opinion.

Comment: @RyanWilson It's a matter of productivity and cleanness. Imagine defining a getter and a setter for every single field in a model layer, I cannot imagine the thousands of lines of boilerplate code

Comment: @RyanWilson The design guidelines shouldn't be considered "opinion".

Comment: @RyanWilson yes, the people that created/maintain the language and specification.  Are they not a good enough authority for you?  Is it very important to you that you write unreadable and unnecessary code?

Comment: @DanielS I figured you were just giving an example, no worries

Comment: @maccettura Design guidelines most certainly are an opinion.  It might be an opinion that you trust a lot, but it's still an opinion.

Comment: @Servy obviously yes, but its nearly the highest authority on what is "good" and "bad".   Regardless, bad code practices shouldn't be perpetuated.  I know you would also point out instances of bad variable names, incorrect casing, etc to those new to the language to help them out.   Auto properties are now 11 years old, I think its (almost) universally accepted they should always be used in lieu of antiquated/redundant GetX/SetX methods

Comment: @maccettura Sure.  You can say that it's an opinion you feel strongly about, or that it's an opinion worth pointing out in comments, or it's an opinion worth following, but *it's still an opinion*.  Saying that it's not an opinion is just factually incorrect, and removes some of your credibility.

Comment: @Servy I think maybe my comment wasn't clear enough.  I put "opinion" in quotes in an attempt to indicate that it should not be considered like any 'ol programmers opinion and that they had some real weight and should be strongly considered.  Maybe that nuance was lost.

Comment: @Servy - have you ever worked in a project with code guidelines in use and ever said to someone "thats your opinion - I prefer to do it this way" - in every project with code guildlines I can currently think of it wasnt an "opinion" of the project members but a strict ruling everyone had to apply - just my 5 cents to the topic

Comment: @RandRandom But weren't not all on the same team, and there isn't a strict rule set that we're all obligated to follow, and that we have no choice in the matter over, so that doesn't apply here.  (Also note that if you're *obligated* to follow strict rules then they're no longer "guidelines", they're rules.  Calling them "guidelines" is rather disingenuous, unless you *are* expected to use your own *opinion* as to whether or not it applies to any given situation.)

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would restrict your generics to a particular interface using a `where` clause:

```
class Test<TA, TB> where TA: IValueGetter
```

This would allow you to then establish the contract based on that interface, so `TA` would always have a `GetValue` method on it. However you could then make the simple step to:

```
class Test {
    public Test(IValueGetter ta, IValueGetter tb)
}
```

Which is simpler and doesn't need any generics. If you wish for your `GetValue` function to then return different types of value and use Generics, then trying making `IGetterSetter` generic instead.

```
class Test<TA, TB> {
    public Test(IGetterSetter<string> ta, IGetterSetter<int> tb)
}
```

So taking your example I would instead move your generics down a level to:

```
interface IGetterSetter<T> {
   void SetValue(T value);
   T GetValue();
}

class BTest : IGetterSetter<string>
class ATest : IGetterSetter<int>
```

Comment: There's no point in making it generic at that point.  Just have the type accept the interface.  Whether you use an interface or the type itself doesn't really matter, it's still not generic.

Comment: Plus the two `GetValue` methods have different signatures.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the type to have a public setter and a public getter, you could define an interface with a property:

```
public interface IValueObject<T>
{
    T Value { get; set; }
}
```

And implement it quite simply:

```
public class StringValue : IValueObject<string>
{
     public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

So, your `Test` class would look like:

```
public class Test<T1, T2>
{
    private IValueObject<T1> _value1;
    private IValueObject<T2> _value2;

    public Test(IValueObject<T1> value1, IValueObject<T2> value2)
    {
        _value1 = value1;
        _value2 = value2;
    }

    void Write()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Value1: " + _value1.Value);
    }
}
```

You can then use this as:

```
Test<string, string> test = new Test<string, string>(new StringValue(), new StringValue());
```